# Best/quickest way to get date from DateTime field in a DataAdapter

Tags: c#, asp.net, datetime

I'm working with a DataAdapter (it's Oracle, but that shouldn't matter) and I'm trying to pull in one particular field.

My code looks like this:

```
    OracleDataAdapter da = new OracleDataAdapter(cmd);
    da.Fill(dtHeaders1);

    txtAuditID_h.Text = dtHeaders1.Rows[0]["AUDIT_ID"].ToString();
    //txtPlanID_h.Text = dtHeaders1.Rows[0]["PLAN_ID"].ToString();
    txtPlanDesc_h.Text = dtHeaders1.Rows[0]["PLAN_DESC"].ToString();
    txtPlanType_h.Text = dtHeaders1.Rows[0]["PLAN_TYPE"].ToString();
    txtProduct_h.Text = dtHeaders1.Rows[0]["PRODUCT"].ToString();
    txtCustNum_h.Text = dtHeaders1.Rows[0]["CUST_NUM"].ToString();
    txtCustName_h.Text = dtHeaders1.Rows[0]["CUST_NM"].ToString();
    txteProTransID_h.Text = dtHeaders1.Rows[0]["WORK_ORDER_NUM"].ToString();

    string ADate = (dtHeaders1.Rows[0]["AUDIT_COMPLETE_DT"].ToString());

    DateTime? dt = string.IsNullOrEmpty(ADate) ? (DateTime?)null : DateTime.Parse(ADate);

    if (dt == null)
    {
            txtAuditCompDt_h.Text = "";
    }
    else
    {
            txtAuditCompDt_h.Text = dt.Value.ToShortDateString();
    }
```

AUDIT_COMPLETE_DT is a DateTime field.  I need to get it into a textbox in "mm/dd/yyyy" format.  This *works*, but I gotta believe there's a better/more efficient and less cludgey way.

Can anyone help me straighten this out?  I just feel like those last 10 lines of code could probably be done with one line if I knew what I was doing?  It's got to be able to handle NULL values, because the date isn't always filled in.

Comment: stringly-typed code... I strongly suspect `dtHeaders1.Rows[0]["AUDIT_COMPLETE_DT"]` is of some `DateTime` related type - just looking at it in debugger should give you an answer or at least help you [edit] post with valid [MCVE].

Answer (score 0):

Here's what I usually do:

```
if (dtHeaders1.Rows[0].IsNull("AUDIT_COMPLETE_DT"))
{
    txtAuditCompDt_h.Text = "";
}
else
{
    txtAuditCompDt_h.Text = ((DateTime)dtHeaders1.Rows[0]["AUDIT_COMPLETE_DT"]).ToString("d");
}
```

It's better because it skips some of the string conversions. I've been considering the following for recent work, but I haven't made the switch yet because I'm not sure it works out to the same performance, and because it requires at least C# 6. It does get you down to one line, though:

```
txtAuditCompDt_h.Text = dtHeaders1.Rows[0].Field<DateTime>("AUDIT_COMPLETE_DT")?.ToString("d") ?? "";
```

Comment: Curious about the locale issues with `ToShortDateString` and the difference with `ToString("d")`, because according to [MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.datetime.toshortdatestring(v=vs.110).aspx) _"the result of calling the ToShortDateString method is identical to calling the DateTime.ToString(String) method with "d" as the format parameter"_

Comment: Yeah. I **know** I read some quirk with this a year or so ago, but I've spent the last 1/2 hour looking for the original reference to include with my answer. I'm still looking, so I'll wait until I finish to edit the answer, either with a link or to remove the comment, but for the moment disregard that part. I don't want to enable cargo cult coding.